# How to generate helm template files without the folder `/templates`?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I create a helm chart directory

`helm create myChart`

After updating the templates and values I run

`helm template .`

Everything looks as expected. Next, I want to output the manifest files into another directory

`helm template . --output-dir ./test`

```sh
wrote ./test/myChart/templates/serviceaccount.yaml
wrote ./test/myChart/templates/service.yaml
wrote ./test/myChart/templates/deployment.yaml
wrote ./test/myChart/templates/tests/test-connection.yaml
```

Is there a way to output just the file manifest without the `mychart/templates`?

```sh
wrote ./test/serviceaccount.yaml
wrote ./test/service.yaml
wrote ./test/deployment.yaml
wrote ./test/test-connection.yaml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is such an option in the Helm command itself, but you can always run the following command.

```
helm template myChart . --output-dir ./test && mv ./test/myChart/templates/* ./test && rm -r ./test/myChart
```

Comment: ok. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something from the helm command. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I think that you have an issue with the command (`$ helm template ...`, instead of `$ helm myChart`)